# Cannot find element using selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

So I have tried looking at the iframes in the website but cannot figure out where this element falls under. Im trying to access an element by class name. Here is my code below and here is the website.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= '/Users/abeelcf/Downloads/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.redfin.com')
zipcode = input("Enter a zip code to look up: ")
search_form = browser.find_element_by_id('search-box-input')
search_form.send_keys(zipcode)
search_form.submit()

#pg 2
browser.find_element_by_id("MapHomeCard_0")
```

The URL is https://www.redfin.com/zipcode/20007

The problem is with the last line. It cannot find element MapHomeCard_0 saying the element **no such element**.

Comment: After you submit the search_form use a wait since the page is loading and will miss finding the element.

Comment: You can directly go to https://www.redfin.com/zipcode/20007 by using `browser.get("https://www.redfin.com/zipcode/20007")` . The problem is with finding the element before the page has loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the page to load after the search_box submit use a web driver wait.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'MapHomeCard_0')))
```

Also import the following

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.redfin.com')
  search_form = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='search-input-box' and @id='search-box-input'][@title='City, Address, School, Agent, ZIP']")))
  search_form.send_keys("20007")
  search_form.submit()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='homecards']/div[@id='MapHomeCard_0']"))).text)
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.homecards>div#MapHomeCard_0"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  LISTED BY REDFIN
  3D WALKTHROUGH
  $464,000
  1 Bed
  1 Bath
  1,014 Sq. Ft.
  2500 Q St NW #412, Washington, DC 20007
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)